# i'm trying to build url but getting exception

Tags: java, http, spring-boot

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder().scheme("http")
                .host("localhost:8080") // here I'm getting error
                .addPathSegment("organization").build();
```

And this is error =>
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected host: localhost:8080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's:

```
HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder().scheme("http")
            .host("localhost")
            .port(8080)
            .addPathSegment("organization").build();
```